# automount process starts 5 minutes after system boots

Tags: networking, upstart, automount, sd-card, autofs

New to ubuntu, and I have been looking every place I can find to fix this issue. I really need my automount process to start when the system starts, not 5 minutes after. I have a program that starts up and gives users the ability to connect an IPhone, Go-Pro, or SD card in a media reader. What's happening is the GUI for the program comes up before the autofs process has started and users get my message "media not available".  This is a stand alone system, can't be connected to a network when in use. I have had it connected to the network for updates but when available for users it has no network connectivity at all. In my research it might be a network setting? Or something with upstart? Sorry to have to ask, went from AIX to RED HAT and now Ubuntu.

Sorry I was not clear the 5minutes is from power on. Below is some output from systemd-analyze critical-chain command:
TOP of CHAIN
***graphical.target @5min 11.240s
multi-user.target @5min 11.240s
autofs.service @5min 10.866s +374ms***
BOTTOM of CHAIN
***kmod-static-nodes.service @1.694s +123ms
system.slice @1.682s
.slice @1.582s***

Output of output of systemd-analyze blame  for autofs.service

374ms autofs.service

John

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1280912/edit) to address: Do you mean 5 minutes after poweron? Or five minutes after login? How did you set up automount? What is the complete output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and `systemd-analyze blame` ?

Comment: Don't add information in comments; edit your question instead. Comments are how we help you improve your question.